# HttpClient not sending Accept-Encoding on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a .NET Core 2.0 console app that does a GET request.

It seems like the published version does not send  `Accept-Encoding` headers for compression on a test machine, but works on my local machine.

I cannot find any other pre-requesites that would make compression fail. Both are running the .NET Core 2.1.4 SDK.

I have tested the console app by running `dotnet Console.dll` in both environments.

1. Publish in VS2017
2. Go to output folder and run `dotnet Console.dll`. Verify header present in Fiddler.
3. Copy entire output folder and deploy onto server
4. Run `dotnet Console.dll` again and verify header missing on the server with Fiddler.

I have tried both `HttpClient` and `RestSharp` and I'm pretty perplexed.

Proof of concept that goes to a page that echoes the request headers:

```
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
            };

 using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
 {
      response = client.GetStringAsync("http://scooterlabs.com/echo").Result;
 }
```

Local environment (Win10)

```
GET http://scooterlabs.com/echo HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: scooterlabs.com
```

Server (Win2008 R2 on AWS)

```
GET http://scooterlabs.com/echo HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: scooterlabs.com
```

Comment: That's the request header though. I'm not sure what scooterlabs uses. Edit: I tried using WebClient and that seems to work fine on the server, so it's something in the HttpClient implementation that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: HttpClient works just fine. You are *not* using HttpClient in your example though, you are using *RestClient*. In any case, if compression didn't work, thousands of developers would have noticed 5 years ago.

Comment: Write a *minimal, reproducible* example and use Fiddler to check the HTTP request and response. If the request headers are there and the service *doesn't* compress the response, it's not a problem with HttpClient

Comment: And what if you add header yourself (and remove `AutomaticDecompression`)?

Comment: @JunWeiLee to put it another way - I'm using HttpClient on Core 2.0 and compression works. You *assume* it doesn't. The **server** isn't HttpClient. If the header doesn't arrive at the server, something (eg firewall) may have removed it. Does the server support compression in the first place? How did you configure the server? What *is* the server?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP means it works from machine A, but doesn't work (header is not sent) from machine B (where machine B is "server").

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The server is irrelevant in this case. The *request* doesn't contain the `Accept-Encoding` header. I'm not assuming anything, Fiddler confirms the header isn't sent.

Comment: @Evk Manually adding the headers *in addition* to setting the handler seems to work on both local machine and server. Really bizarre why the difference in environment would trigger it. Post that up as an answer and I'll accept it!              `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));`

Comment: That's quite strange still. I'd better verify that decompression really works, because if it doesn't want to set this header itself - maybe because it won't be able to decompress response?

Comment: @Evk I have verified this by retrieving google.com with the header forced. Scenario 1) Disable compression in `HttpClientHandler` . Verify binary data received. Scenario 2) Enable compression in `HttpClientHandler`. Verify plaintext received. So it is receiving compressed data, and can decompress it automatically.

Comment: Where did you get the header? From the log of dotnet Console.dll itself, or using IIS log? Since I suspect if you are using IIS as proxy for dotnet process

Comment: @WilliamSYWong The headers are sniffed from Fiddler. WebClient works fine, and if I force HttpClient to add the header it works fine as well.

Comment: I should ask in this way: did your server use IIS? Since it is common to use IIS as proxy to run dotnet process (by restarting dotnet if crashed)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I apologise for the previous snarky comment. I've deleted it and updated the question to be clearer by replacing the word `server` with `another machine`.

Comment: @WilliamSYWong The web server is not relevant here as this is a console app. This is a problem with the `http request` headers missing `Accept-Encoding` from a console app.

Comment: nope, if you are using IIS to forward your request, it might modify your request header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164824/discussion-between-jun-wei-lee-and-william-sy-wong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess would be that's because WinHttp library, which is used by default by HttpClient on windows [does not support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066(v=vs.85).aspx) gzip\deflate on windows versions before Windows 8.1+. When supported - WinHttp will also set Accept-Encoding header. So on Windows Server 2008 when .NET routes request through WinHttp - it either sets this option and it is ignored, or it checks if this option is supported and if not - just not sets it.

If you set this header manually (like `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));`) - option is still ignored but header passes through and server returns compressed response. If supported - WinHttp will decompress that response and remove Content-Encoding header, so response will arrive decompressed to .NET. If not supported - response will arrive compressed and .NET itself will decompress it if you set `AutomaticDecompression`.

So to conclude - on Windows versions before 8.1 it seems you need to set both `AutomaticDecompression` and related `Accept-Encoding` headers for this to work as expected.

Comment: In Windows 7, if you set manually the header (something like: `httprequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");`, and don't specify `AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;`, the stream will arrive compressed with one of the preferred methods (gzip, if available, in the sample code). `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream` and `System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream` can be used to decompress the stream and copy it to a MemoryStream for the final `StreamReader.ReadToEnd([MemoryStream])`.

Answer (score 3):

Building on Ivan and Evk's answers, it does appear that this is an issue specific to older versions of Windows (older than Win8.1). Here is how to work around and successfully handle compression on older versions of Windows.

```
   var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
                };

   using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
   {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
        response = client.GetStringAsync("http://scooterlabs.com/echo").Result;
   }
```

`AutomaticDecompression` **must** be set in addition to the headers, otherwise you will get the compressed payload instead.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer, though I've tried to reproduce this on Azure's Win Server 2008 R2 with different Echo servers (.NET Core SDK 2.1.4)

```
// http://scooterlabs.com/echo output

[headers] => Array
(
    [Connection] => Keep-Alive
    [Host] => scooterlabs.com
)


// http://httpbin.org/headers output
{
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }
}

// https://postman-echo.com/headers output
{
    "headers": {
        "host": "postman-echo.com",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
    }
}
```

On Win10 indeed I also have those headers present.

```
// http://scooterlabs.com/echo output
[headers] => Array
(
    [Connection] => Keep-Alive
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Host] => scooterlabs.com
)

// http://httpbin.org/headers output
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }
}

// https://postman-echo.com/headers output
{
    "headers": {
        "host": "postman-echo.com",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
    }
}
```

which makes me think that `HttpClient`'s `Accept-Encoding` header is really not supported on WS 2008 R2.

Comment: Thanks, just confirmed with a Windows 8.1 VM that it is indeed set. Combined with @Evk's answer we can conclude that it might be something the Core team might want to look at, as it really can handle the compression.